# How to apply a python decorator to a function?

Tags: python, decorator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Python decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

Could you please give a short code example that explains decorators?

Comment: here's a tutorial I wrote: https://www.codementor.io/python/tutorial/introduction-to-decorators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decorator takes the function definition and creates a new function that executes this 
function and transforms the result.

```
@deco
def do():
    ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
do = deco(do)
```

Example:

```
def deco(func):
    def inner(letter):
        return func(letter).upper()  #upper
    return inner  # return a function object

#This
@deco
def do(number):
    return chr(number)  # number to letter
#end

# is equivalent to this
def do2(number):
    return chr(number)

do2 = deco(do2)
#end


# 65 <=> 'a'
print(do(65))
print(do2(65))
>>> B
>>> B
```

To understand the decorator, it is important to notice, that decorator created a new function *do* which is *inner* that executes *func* and transforms the result.

Answer (score 5):

```
def spam(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print "SPAM"
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@spam #this is the same as doing eggs = spam(eggs)
def eggs():
    print "Eggs?"
```

Notice you can also use classes to write decorators

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "SPAM"
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@Spam
def something():
    pass
```